# How can i multiply the values in two dissimilar dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to multiply the values of a dictionary and a nested dictionary. The keys of one are slightly similar to the keys of another, which should help out a little bit.

```
     dict1 = {'a' :{'irrelevant': 1}, 'b' :{'cat': 2}, 'c': {'train': 3}}
     dict2 = {'a2' : 4, 'b2' : 5, 'd2': 10}

     multiplied_values = []

     for key, value in dict1:
           for k, v in value:
               for key2, value2 in dict2:  

                   if key == str(key2.split('2')[0]):
                          multiplied_values.append(v*value2)
     print(multiplied_values)
```

I would like to get a list of [4, 10] for this
 Instead I get the following error message:

```
for key, value in dict1:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the loops that you are trying to run for each dictionary is not iterating over the keys and the values properly. You can accomplish this by using  `.items()`. This will give you back a set of (key, value) pairs that can be iterated over.

```
dict1 = {'a' :{'irrelevant': 1}, 'b' :{'cat': 2}, 'c': {'train': 3}}
dict2 = {'a2' : 4, 'b2' : 5, 'd2': 10}

multiplied_values = []

for key, value in dict1.items():
   for k, v in value.items():
       for key2, value2 in dict2.items():  

           if key == str(key2.split('2')[0]):
                  multiplied_values.append(v*value2)

print(multiplied_values)
```

Check [this link](https://www.mkyong.com/python/python-how-to-loop-a-dictionary/) out for more information if you're still having difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using `items()` on your dictionary, you can remove the inner most loop entirely:

```
dict1 = {'a' :{'irrelevant': 1}, 'b' :{'cat': 2}, 'c': {'train': 3}}
dict2 = {'a2' : 4, 'b2' : 5, 'd2': 10}

multiplied_values = []

for key, value in dict1.items():
   for k, v in value.items():
       product = v * dict2[key + '2']
       multiplied_values.append(product)

print(multiplied_values)
```

Since you are looking for a specific key in `dict2` and can build that key from the key in `dict1`, you don't need to loop over all of the keys in `dict2`.

Comment: Thank you. 

But what if the keys in dict2 didnt all have '2' as the final character. what if we had

dict2 = {'a235' : 4, 'b200012' : 5, 'd2897636': 10}?

Much appreciated

Comment: @CyrusWyett Yes, in that case, my solution won't work. You should see if there is a pattern that you can exploit in other ways. What is the pattern in the keys? Do all the keys have the same digits on the end? Is the first letter always a letter with the rest digits?

Answer (score 0):

This version uses list comprehensions. As first step we "flatten" dictionary `dict` to remove the inner dictionaries. Second step is making the final product by combining the `dict2` and flattened dictionary:

```
dict1 = {'a' :{'irrelevant': 1}, 'b' :{'cat': 2}, 'c': {'train': 3}}
dict2 = {'a2' : 4, 'b2' : 5, 'd2': 10}

k1 = dict((k+'2', *[*v.values()]) for k, v in dict1.items()) # {'a2': 1, 'b2': 2, 'c2': 3}

print([v*dict2[k] for k, v in k1.items() if k in dict2])
```

Prints:

```
[4, 10]
```